# wordpress - zion theme Where can I find the page templates?

Tags: wordpress, templates

I have the free wordpress zion template (child of green-lantern template).
The [theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/zion/) says:
Zion is a Cross-Browser Compatible theme that works on All leading web browsers. It has 4 page layouts, 2 page templates, It has five widgets available (one sidebar, four footers), and using the sidebar widget also enables you to make a two-column design.
But I can't find the place to activate these page layouts or templates.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think these features are available only in green lantern PRO version.

Please, check the link of the theme to see further infos:

https://weblizar.com/themes/green-lantern-premium-theme/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but at https://wordpress.org/themes/zion/ is mentioned "It has 4 page layouts, 2 page templates, It has five widgets available" So I'm still looking for them.

Comment: I suppose is based on green-lantern, so if you have the 4 page layout of green -lantern you can use it inside zion.
I donwloaded zion theme and don't have has proper layout. Only modify the styles of green-lantern